# How secure is storing passwords with a salt and crypt()?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, salt, password-encryption

Coding an application that needs to store user's passwords for login.

At the moment, I am using the following code:

```
<?php
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $salt = "pepper";
    $password = crypt($password,$salt);
?>
```

Exactly how secure is this method? For instance, if someone managed to get the `$salt`, how easy would it be for them to decrypt the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no cryptanalist, but that method is rather weak, because the default hash algorithm used is a modified version of DES and DES can be cracked with relatively unexpensive hardware in a short time: given that non-modified DES was cracked in 1998 by [EFF Deep Crack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker) in 22 hours, cracking or finding a collision for this modified version shouldn't be that difficult.

Furthermore, [`crypt` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man3/crypt.3.html) (the function PHP is wrapping on *nix systems) reports:

> Warning: The key space consists of 2**56 equal 7.2e16 possible  values.
>   Exhaustive  searches  of  this  key  space are possible using massively parallel computers.  Software, such as  crack(1),  is  available  which will  search  the  portion  of this key space that is generally used by humans for passwords.  Hence, password selection  should,  at  minimum, avoid  common  words  and  names.

Instead, use SHA-512 and perform multiple hashing rounds with:

```
// Take advantage of mcrypt extension if it is installed!
// Otherwise, generate $salt in any other way, but don't use a fixed one
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
$hash = crypt($password, '$6$rounds=10000$' . $salt . '$');
echo $hash;
```

SHA-512 with enough rounds is considered an industrial standard for password hashes in the *nix land, with `mcrypt_create_iv` providing a good (in the sense of entropy) `$salt`.

Final notice: **make sure you use a proper salt and generate a different one for each user**.

Comment: This reduces the chance of collisions, but the question was how easy it would be to decrypt the data, which is near impossible whichever salt you use.

Comment: The OP wrote: "Exactly how secure is this method? **For instance** ...". Key decryption was only an example of the possible issues. Why downvote?

Comment: I stand corrected. It was indeed an example.

Comment: `$password = $_GET['password'];
 $salt = 'pepper';
 $password = crypt($password, '$6$rounds=10000$' . $salt . '$');
 echo $password;`
is not working.

Comment: Use a different name for the resulting hash. This should work: `<?php $password='testdummy'; $salt = 'pepper'; $hash = crypt($password, '$6$rounds=10000$' . $salt . '$'); echo $hash; ?>`